# Cannot get declared variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, global-variables

Consider a javascript file `script.js` which contains the code `alert(theVar);`

Now, i linked the js file to the document like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var theVar= 'a alert';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script> //Contains alert(theVar);
```

The variable `theVar` is used and i get a alert. This works fine.

When,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     var theVar= 'a alert';
 </script>
```

is used, i am not getting a alert.

I know the problem is because of the variable, which is declared after loading the js file.

But is there any way to get the variable declared anywhere in the document ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in `script.js` do

```
window.onload = function() { alert ( theVar ) }
```

Or your favorite library dom ready fn, so it invokes the callback after a certain event instead of immediately.

Though, this really depends on what kind of functionality `script.js` has, which you have not specified thus far.

Answer (score 1):

The important bit is that code gets *executed* in the appropriate order. You should delay the call to `alert(theVar)` until the document gets fully loaded. For instance, you can attach an `onload` event handler to the `window` object.

It's also worth noting that calling external *.js files does not affect the way code gets run.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution:

Move the `script.js` inclusion to the last row of the `body`. That way a variable declared at any point in the document can be used.

The technical solution:

Inside `script.js`, hook on to the `window.onload` event before doing any evaluating. The result is the same as with the simpler solution, but allows you to keep you script tags in the head (or anywhere for that matter).